# Construct QueryDict from string representation

Tags: python, django

I have a QueryDict in string form:
`"<QueryDict: {'order_by': ['-time_updated'], 'page_size': ['500']}>"`

I wish to construct a `QueryDict` object from this string. Does `QueryDict` have a built in way to accomplish this? (the docs don't seem to point towards that)

If not, what would be the best way to create it manually?

Comment: Why did you end up with this string in the first place? Please do *not* do this, this will only make things worse. You should try to return a `QueryDict`, *not* its string representation.

Comment: PS: I get the QueryDict from a middleware which uses `request.body`. Changing that part of code is a difficult (but not completely impossible) option.

Comment: @a3ya: but if this is the body, then normally `request.POST` should contain the query dictionary.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the middleware logs POST bodies correctly. This could potentially come from `request.GET` too.

Comment: I don't understand one thing. Why do you need it? Don't you have an access to initial QueryDict? Just having access to string representation?

Comment: @AndreyNelubin Yep. I just have access to the string representation. I get it as part of generated logs, which include the request type, status, path, and the content (if POST) or query string (if GET).

Comment: I know that there are security flaws with `eval` and such like, but if you **entirely** trust the source, and know it hasn't been interfered with, you could try something like `import ast; query_info = ast.literal_eval("<QueryDict: {'order_by': ['-time_updated'], 'page_size': ['500']}>"[12:-1])`... Once again, do **not** use this unless you know the source to be trustworthy, as it can be a potential vector for arbitrary code.

Comment: @EdWard The source is guaranteed to be safe!